How does camera intrinsic parameters change after undistortion
Here is my goal: I have used OpenCV to estimate a camera's intrinsic parameters and distortion coefficients. In order to avoid having to deal with the camera's distortion going forward, I would like to create a wrapper around cv.VideoCapture.read() which undistorts and crops the image right off the bat, as if there was no distortion in the first place.
After I perform this undistortion, I need this "new" cameras intrinsic parameters. I can always call cv.calibrateCamera a second time, passing in a copy of the original imagePoints array but with each point's coordinates remapped according to the initial calibration, but that seems wasteful. Is there an easy way to compute the new camera intrinsic parameters?
